# Server maintenance landing page - can it be on HTTP?

Tags: nginx, maintenance

We are running two accounting systems on ruby on rails and sometimes we have to do maintenance tasks which cause downtimes, or just that they are simpler to do with downtimes.
i.a. This week we where migrating our whole suite of lxc containers to a set of SSDs, from HDDs.
accounting systems are accessed over HTTPS at fakturabank.no and snotr.no

We are running a LXD server and have one container specifically for serving the maintenance page, a static html page.  Which we are planning to move to another server, so we can keep it up across reboots.
To enable the maintenance page now, we boot up the maintenance container and edit the netplan settings with the ip adresses of the accountingsofware containers, then we turn of the accountingsofware container, and run `netplan apply && systemctl nginx restart` on the maintenance container.

On the accounting systems we have SSL certificates from letsencrypt, as of now the maintenance container only accepts traffic on HTTP as it does not have any SSL certificate. This leads to that users which are in the system at time we start the maintenance will not be redirected to the maintenance page.

I want to keep it as simple as possible to enable the maintenance mode.
the maintenance page will only show information so i don't see how it would be beneficial for it to be on https.
How can i configure nginx to do this? Is this a dumb idea?
Will my users get the warning that this page is insecure?

Another idea :(
Do i have to add to my procedure to request new shared certificate on the maintenance server whenever i want to use it?

Comment: There are people who have [setup their browsers to not talk plaintext any more](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/https-only-prefs).

Comment: @anx Sad times, I don't get why people would do that! Well, sortof, from a non techy- point of view i get that it is as simple as, I only visit pages which are secure. It does not mean anything more than that the connection is encrypted, you could still be hitting "wrong" server, any DNS spoofing or modifications could fuck with that . AAAAHHHH!  but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should use HTTPS in your maintenance server.

- people use bookmarks
- browsers show HTTP as insecure
- Browsers start using HTTPS as default if no protocol is specified
- if your server provides [HSTS headers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (which it should) the browsers which visited your server before will show big security warnings and reject to talk to your server

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how familiar you are with letsencrypt but I'll ask anyways.
when I request a new certificate on the maintenance server, will that invalidate the one on the accountingsoftware container? will it work fine to revert back to that one when the maintenance is done?